# Insert value to database in CodeIgniter; I have array <input> tag

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter

How can I insert a value to database having an array values in my `<input>` tag. I'm making online library system; this part is I'm adding a book to database sometimes a book have more than 1 author.

Now I use implode to insert but the 2 authors are sharing in 1 one column. What I want they have to be in different column when inserting to tbl_authors. I insert book details to tbl_books and for authors in tbl_authors. I've tried for each but I can only do it when displaying data when insert I have no idea

```
   foreach($test as value)
   {
   'author_name' => $value[' no idea what i need to put here']
    }
```

[image: Html Code]

[image: Add Book Page]

[image: Problem, 2 authors sharing on 1 column. I need To separate them]

```
  public function insertbooks()
            {
              $data=array(
            'book_id'         =>        $this->db->insert_id(),
            'book_title'    =>      $this->input->post('booktitle',true),
            'section_id'      =>        $this->input->post('section',true),
            /*'book_author'   =>        $this->input->post('bookauthor',true),*/
            'book_serial'   =>    $this->input->post('serial',true),
            'book_qty'      =>      $this->input->post('bookqty',true),
            );
            $sql1  = $this->db->insert('tbl_books',$data);
            $author_name=implode(',', $this->input->post('bookauthor',true));
            $data2=array(
            'book_id'       =>    $this->db->insert_id(),
            'author_name'   =>    $author_name
            );
            $sql2  = $this->db->insert('tbl_authors',$data2);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably need to have each author inserted as a different row not column.

To achieve this, you should iterate authors array and make each insert separately, like:

```
public function insertbooks()
{
    $data = array(
        'book_id'       =>    $this->db->insert_id(),
        'book_title'    =>    $this->input->post('booktitle',true),
        'section_id'    =>    $this->input->post('section',true),
        'book_serial'   =>    $this->input->post('serial',true),
        'book_qty'      =>    $this->input->post('bookqty',true),
    );
    $sql1  = $this->db->insert('tbl_books',$data);

    $book_id = $this->db->insert_id();

    foreach ($this->input->post('bookauthor',true) as $author) {
        $data2=array(
          'book_id'       =>    $book_id,
          'author_name'   =>    $author
        );
        $sql2  = $this->db->insert('tbl_authors',$data2);
    }
}
```

This way, you'll have separate record for each book / author relationshi.